# Place ADBanner on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iad

My App recently got rejected, because two of my third-party-libs use the `AdSupport` Framework and Apple couldn't find any "Apple-Ad" Banners anywhere, when they were testing it. So I updated my code and placed a `ADBannerView` as a `subview` on a cell in my `UITableView`.

But this doesn't seem to work and I get error codes like

ADErrorDomain Code 4: App has iAD Configuration Errors and other errors ..

When I add the banner view as a `subview` of a `UIViewController`s view, it works pretty well.

Is there a problem with the ad, or can't I place the ad on a `UITableViewCell`? Or is there a way to place an `ADBannerView` on a table view cell?

**EDIT:**

I place a `ADBannerView` just like in that tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/iad-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

**EDIT 2:**

This it the test-code to verify, if the iAd integration works as expected.

//this is for building up the table view cell

```
- (void) initializeAllAdTableViewCells {

    [self initializeAdTableViewCellWithRow:1 inSection:0];

    [self initializeAdTableViewCellWithRow:4 inSection:0];

    [self initializeAdTableViewCellWithRow:5 inSection:0]; 
}

- (void) initializeAdTableViewCellWithRow:(NSUInteger) row inSection:(NSUInteger) section {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]];

        ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];

        adView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [cell addSubview:adView];

        //store ad tableViewCell for later
        [self internalRegisterAdTableViewCell:cell withRow:row inSection:section];

        adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        adView.delegate = self;

        [adView release];

        [cell autorelease]

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    int adCellCount = [[self adCellsForSection:section] count];

    return [data count] + adCellCount; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self adCellForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];

    if (cell == nil)    {

        //create other cells
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps some code on what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You're releasing the AdBannerView and it probably hasn't even had a chance to load the ad into the view before you do that. You'll want to set your class up as a delegate of the ad and then you can have the ad insert a row into your table when the ad is available and then remove the row with the ad when it isn't. Ads aren't always available and you'll use - bannerViewDidLoadAd.

Comment: Ok, i've updated my code. It creates the TableViewCells and stores the Advertisment TableViewCells in a dictionary, bevore the build-up of the tableview.

Comment: You're still releasing your AdBannerView while you want it to be getting used. You need to hold onto a reference to it as long as you want to have an ad displayed.

Comment: The reference is beeing held by adding the ADBannerView on the TableView. With [cell adSubview:adView]; the retaincounter of the ADBannerView is beeing increased. And it receives the error messages through the delegates.